# Is it possible to pass .net data through Foundation's NSNotificationCenter?

Tags: c#, xamarin, nsnotificationcenter, nsobject, nsnotifications

I work on a .net mobile cross platform application on Xamarin.

I would like to send datas from a ViewController A to a ViewController B. 
In my ViewController A, I have a dictionary. In my ViewController B, I want to create/edit a Key/Value pair and add it back to my dictionary in my ViewController A.

To do this, I think I use NSNotificationCenter.

However, NSNotificationCenter allows only to pass data as NSObject (from Foundation framework). The data I need to send comes from .net Framework Dictionary (from System.Collections.Generic).

What would be the best practice to achieve such a transfer of data ?

I already tried do cast explicitely data between .net and foundation frameworks and doing some things like "NSObject.FromObject(keyValuePair)". I don't know if the reverse operation is possible...

Comment: Passing limited data between VCs is commonly just done after the creation of the VC and before the first VC presents the second VC (if you are using segues, then that is the place to do it). When trying to pass data between VCs via notification center, now you are involving the VCs life cycle and while multiple VCs can be present at a time, only you can determine if that is correct for your needs. But iOS/Cocoa is based upon the MVC (Model View Controller) architecture, so typically you have models behind those VCs that are actually the ones contain the data that the VCs are pulling/pushing to

Comment: You can of course implement different architectural patterns other then MVC (with some caveats), i.e MVVMCross provides an MVVM pattern to standard iOS VCs/UIView/etc...), the Viper pattern is another (which I personally use). None of these, MVC/MVVM/Viper/..., are using notification center to pass data between VCs.

Comment: Here is a official sample passing data between pages.(https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/xamarin-forms/Navigation/PassingData/).Not suggest using `NSNotificationCenter` ,it will make passing data complicated.